# Vetor gradiente para uso na função optim

Tags: r

Já procurei muito, em diversos fóruns e em muitas páginas sobre estimação de parâmetros via função `optim` do R e não encontrei nada sobre como acrescentar a função gradiente em um script, de tal forma que as derivadas sejam calculadas via alguma função do R seja, `_deriv()_` ou `_deriv3()_` ou via pacote `_NumDeriv_` ou pacote `_Deriv_`. Preciso calcular o gradiente com o intuito de tentar melhorar meu processo de estimação e é impossível fazer as derivadas na mão pois minha função log de verossimilhança é muito extensa.

Consigo fazer as derivadas no `_Maple 16_`, mas gostaria de saber obter o gradiente no `_R_` de forma mais automatizada. O código abaixo é um script para estimação de parâmetros da Birnbaum-Saunders univariada com dois parâmetros, caso consiga implementar o gradiente neste script eu conseguiria implementar no meu código mais complicado!

Ao compilar o código abaixo tenho obtido as vezes parâmetros negativos, o que é um absurdo, pois `_alpha_`, `_beta_` e `_t_` são positivos. Imagino que com o gradiente isso possa deixar de ocorrer.

```
library(VGAM)
alpha<-2
beta <-1
truevalue <- c(alpha,beta)
n=1000
N=300
m=matrix(ncol=2,nrow=N)

for (i in 1:N){
x <- rnorm(n,mean = 0,sd=sqrt((alpha^2)/4))
t <- beta*(1+2*x^2+2*x*sqrt(1+x^2)) #t possui distribuição birnbaum-Saunders com parâmetros alpha e beta
#t <- rbisa(n, alpha, beta)
#sum(1*(t<0))

#Função Densidade da distribuição birnbaum-saunders

f <-function(theta){
  alpha <- abs(theta[1])
  beta  <- abs(theta[2])
  d <- (1/(2*alpha*beta*sqrt(2*pi)))*(sqrt(beta/t)+(beta/t)^(3/2))*exp(-    (1/(2*alpha^2))*((t/beta)+(beta/t)-2))
  return(d)
}

#Forma 1 da log verossimilhança

# log.ver <- function(theta){
#   alpha <- abs(theta[1])
#   beta  <- abs(theta[2])
#   l <- sum(log(f(theta)))
#   return(l)
# }

#Forma 2 da log verossimilhança

log.ver <- function(theta){
  alpha <- abs(theta[1])
  beta  <- abs(theta[2])
  l <- sum(log((1/(2*alpha*beta*sqrt(2*pi)))*(sqrt(beta/t)+    (beta/t)^(3/2))*exp(-(1/(2*alpha^2))*((t/beta)+(beta/t)-2))))
  return(l)
}

alpha_0 <- 3
beta_0 <- 4
start <- c(alpha_0,beta_0)
opt <- optim(start,log.ver,method="BFGS",hessian = F,control=list(fnscale=-1))
m[i,]=opt$par
}

#Calculating the average of each column of the array of parameters m
mest=colMeans(m)

#calculating the standard deviation of each column of the array of     parameters m
dest=apply(m,2,sd)

#root mean square error in the calculation of each column of the array of     parameters m in relation to the true value of the parameter
eqm=function(x,opt){ 
  N=length(x)
  sqrt(sum(((x-opt)^2))/N)}

#Estimated mean squared error of each parameter 
eqmest=c(eqm(x=m[,1],opt=alpha),
         eqm(x=m[,2],opt=beta))

# Table with the true values of the parameters and the average
# Standard deviation and mean square error of the estimated parameters
tab=data.frame(truevalue,mean=mest,sd=dest,eqm=eqmest)
tab
```

Agradeço muito a ajuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui uma solução para o gradiente e ainda acrescentei a Hessiana, com as três linhas de código que estão comentadas no meio do script é possível verificar a coerência do código!

```
    rm(list=ls())
cat("\014")
library(VGAM)
library(Deriv)
n=100
N=300
m=matrix(ncol=2,nrow=N)
f <- quote((log((1/(2*alpha*beta*sqrt(2*pi)))*(sqrt(beta/t)+(beta/t)^(3/2))*exp(-(1/(2*alpha^2))*((t/beta)+(beta/t)-2)))))
fd1 <- Deriv(f,"alpha")
fd2 <- Deriv(f,"beta")

hd11 <- Deriv(fd1,"alpha")
hd12 <- Deriv(fd1,"beta")
hd21 <- Deriv(fd2,"alpha")
hd22 <- Deriv(fd2,"beta")

for (i in 1:N){
  alpha<-2
  beta <-1
x <- rnorm(n,mean = 0,sd=sqrt((alpha^2)/4))
t <- beta*(1+2*x^2+2*x*sqrt(1+x^2)) #t possui distribuição birnbaum-Saunders com parâmetros alpha e beta

rm(alpha,beta)
log.ver <- function(theta){
  alpha <- theta[1]
  beta  <- theta[2]
  l <- sum(log((1/(2*alpha*beta*sqrt(2*pi)))*(sqrt(beta/t)+(beta/t)^(3/2))*exp(-(1/(2*alpha^2))*((t/beta)+(beta/t)-2))))
  return(-l)
}

grad<-function(theta){
  alpha <- theta[1]
  beta  <- theta[2]
  gd <- cbind(eval(fd1),eval(fd2))
  return(-colSums(gd, na.rm = FALSE))
}

Hess<-function(theta){
  alpha <- theta[1]
  beta  <- theta[2]
  matrix(c(-sum(eval(hd11)),-sum(eval(hd12)),
         -sum(eval(hd21)),-sum(eval(hd22))),nrow = 2,ncol = 2)
}

# theta <- c(opt$par[1],opt$par[2])
# Hess(theta)
# opt$hessian

alpha_0 <- 10
beta_0 <- 10
start <- c(alpha_0,beta_0)
opt <- optim(start,log.ver,method="BFGS",gr=grad,hessian = T)
#opt <- optim(start,log.ver,method="BFGS",hessian = F)

m[i,]=opt$par
}
alpha<-2
beta <-1
#Calculating the average of each column of the array of parameters m
mest=colMeans(m)

#calculating the standard deviation of each column of the array of parameters m
dest=apply(m,2,sd)

#root mean square error in the calculation of each column of the array of parameters m in relation to the true value of the parameter
eqm=function(x,opt){ 
  N=length(x)
  sqrt(sum(((x-opt)^2))/N)}

#Estimated mean squared error of each parameter 
eqmest=c(eqm(x=m[,1],opt=alpha),
         eqm(x=m[,2],opt=beta))

# Table with the true values of the parameters and the average
# Standard deviation and mean square error of the estimated parameters
#m
truevalue <- c(alpha,beta)
tab=data.frame(truevalue,mean=mest,sd=dest,eqm=eqmest)
tab
```

Answer (score 2):

Trabalhei sobre o código original da sua resposta e identifiquei dois problemas:

1. Por padrão, a função *optim* realiza **minimizações**, que podem ser convertido em um problema de **maximização** se você trocar o sinal da função objetivo. Por isso, o ponto que a sua otimização está retornando é um ponto de mínimo. De todo jeito, já vi que você resolveu isso na segunda resposta.
2. Se o seu estimador de máxima verossimilhança precisar satisfazer condições, você vai ter que usar um algoritmo que faça a otimização levando em conta essas restrições. Fornecer um gradiente não resolverá esse problema diretamente, apenas deixará sua otimização mais rápida e mais precisa. Isso eventualmente pode fazer com que você encontre pontos de ótimo apenas na região que te interessa, mas existem problemas em que a otimização irrestrita **mesmo com o gradiente** vai te levar a resultados absurdos. Na verdade, eu acho que é uma boa estratégia não implementar gradientes até que se experiencie problemas de convergência ou ineficiência no código. No seu caso, acho que isso ainda não ocorre.

Dito isso, minha solução para o seu problema usa a função *constrOptim* do pacote *stats*, que resolve problemas de minimização usando os mesmos algoritmos do *optim*, mas garante que a otimização será feita com restrições.

O código abaixo ilustra a utilização da função *constrOptim* no seu problema, onde faço com que alfa e beta sejam positivos através dos parâmetros *ui* e *ci*.

```
library(VGAM)
alpha<-2
beta <-1
truevalue <- c(alpha,beta)
n=1000
N=300
m=matrix(ncol=2,nrow=N)

for (i in 1:N){
  x <- rnorm(n,mean = 0,sd=sqrt((alpha^2)/4))
  t <- beta*(1+2*x^2+2*x*sqrt(1+x^2)) #t possui distribuição birnbaum-Saunders com parâmetros alpha e beta
  #t <- rbisa(n, alpha, beta)
  #sum(1*(t<0))

  #Função Densidade da distribuição birnbaum-saunders

  f <-function(theta){
    alpha <- abs(theta[1])
    beta  <- abs(theta[2])
    d <- (1/(2*alpha*beta*sqrt(2*pi)))*(sqrt(beta/t)+(beta/t)^(3/2))*exp(-    (1/(2*alpha^2))*((t/beta)+(beta/t)-2))
    return(d)
  }

  #Forma 1 da log verossimilhança

  # log.ver <- function(theta){
  #   alpha <- abs(theta[1])
  #   beta  <- abs(theta[2])
  #   l <- sum(log(f(theta)))
  #   return(l)
  # }

  #Forma 2 da log verossimilhança

  log.ver <- function(theta){
    alpha <- abs(theta[1])
    beta  <- abs(theta[2])
    l <- -sum(log((1/(2*alpha*beta*sqrt(2*pi)))*(sqrt(beta/t)+(beta/t)^(3/2))*exp(-(1/(2*alpha^2))*((t/beta)+(beta/t)-2))))
    return(l)
  }

  alpha_0 <- 2
  beta_0 <- 3
  start <- c(alpha_0,beta_0)
  opt <- constrOptim(start, log.ver, grad = NULL, ui = diag(2), ci = rep(0,2), method = 'Nelder-Mead')

  m[i,]=opt$par
}

#Calculating the average of each column of the array of parameters m
mest=colMeans(m)

#calculating the standard deviation of each column of the array of     parameters m
dest=apply(m,2,sd)

#root mean square error in the calculation of each column of the array of     parameters m in relation to the true value of the parameter
eqm=function(x,opt){ 
  N=length(x)
  sqrt(sum(((x-opt)^2))/N)}

#Estimated mean squared error of each parameter 
eqmest=c(eqm(x=m[,1],opt=alpha),
         eqm(x=m[,2],opt=beta))

# Table with the true values of the parameters and the average
# Standard deviation and mean square error of the estimated parameters
tab=data.frame(truevalue,mean=mest,sd=dest,eqm=eqmest)
tab
```

Comment: Obrigado @FernandoCorrêa, em relação a sua resposta 1, note que em meu código acrescento na função _optim_ o termo _control=list(fnscale=-1)_, isso significa que estou fazendo uma maximização. Em relação a sua resposta 2, concordo plenamente, porém, como pode perceber, após algumas correções que postei em minha resposta o processo de estimação mesmo sem o gradiente não está ruim. Isso não é meu problema, pois esse código é um teste, eu realmente necessito de ajustar o gradiente conforme expliquei na minha pergunta para resolver a estimação em outros modelos. Mais agradeço sua ajuda!